# How to get text from specific span from multiple elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, find

Hello Friends I have span with class .amount how can i get price from this span i have tried but i am not able to point out the exact location

**Html**

```
<li class="radio">
<input class="tmcp-field nav nav-pills fabric-layer-pattern test  tm-product-image tm-epo-field tmcp-radio use_images" data-image="http://localhost/mbox_server/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/pattern.png"  type="radio">
<label for="tmcp_choice_14_2_39">
       <img class="tmlazy  radio_image" alt="Elegant" src="http://localhost/mbox_server/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/pattern.png">
        <span class="tc-label radio_image_label">Elegant</span>
    </label>    
<span class="price tc-price  hidden">
      <span class="amount">500</span>
 </span>        

</li>
```

**Javascript**

```
   $('.fabric-layer-pattern').click(function() {
 var spanEl1 = $(this).parent('li.radio').find('span.amount');
 var priceee = spanEl1.text(); //Get text
     console.log(price);
    // this alert is coming two times empty after that price will come 
     alert(priceee);
    });
```

**Updated Html Code**

```
<ul>



<li class="radio">
<input class="tmcp-field nav nav-pills fabric-layer-pattern test  tm-product-image tm-epo-field tmcp-radio use_images" data-image="http://localhost/mbox_server/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/pattern.png" data-imagep="" data-imagel="" tabindex="37" type="radio">
<label for="tmcp_choice_14_0_37"><img class="tmlazy  radio_image" alt="Elegant" src="http://localhost/mbox_server/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/pattern.png">
  <span class="tc-label radio_image_label">Elegant</span></label>   

    <span class="price tc-price  hidden"><span class="amount">500</span>      </span>       
   </li>



  <li class="radio">
        <input class="tmcp-field nav nav-pills fabric-layer-pattern test  tm-product-image tm-epo-field tmcp-radio use_images"  type="radio">
  <label for="tmcp_choice_14_1_38"><img class="tmlazy  radio_image" alt="Elegant" src="http://localhost/mbox_server/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/pattern.png">
   <span class="tc-label radio_image_label">Elegant</span></label>  
      <span class="price tc-price  hidden"><span class="amount">500</span>   </span>        

 </li>

 <li class="radio">
  <input class="tmcp-field nav nav-pills fabric-layer-pattern test  tm-product-image tm-epo-field tmcp-radio use_images" type="radio">
  <label for="tmcp_choice_14_2_39"><img class="tmlazy  radio_image" alt="Elegant" src="http://localhost/mbox_server/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/pattern.png">
  <span class="tc-label radio_image_label">Elegant</span></label>   
 <span class="price tc-price  hidden"><span class="amount">500</span>     </span>       

</li>

</ul>
```

please suggest something...

Comment: Will there be more than one set of inputs/spans?

Comment: can post error that you are getting with this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `parent()` and `find()` to have specific element from multiple elements.

```
var spanEl = $(this).parent('li').find('span.amount');
var price = spanEl.text(); //Get text
console.log(price);
```

```js
/*$('.fabric-layer-pattern').click(function() {
     var spanEl = $(this).parent('li').find('span.amount');
     var price = spanEl.text(); //Get text
     console.log(price);
});*/
 $('.fabric-layer-pattern').click(function() {
 var spanEl1 = $(this).parent('li.radio').find('span.amount');
 var priceee = spanEl1.text(); //Get text
     console.log(priceee);
    // this alert is coming two times empty after that price will come 
     alert(priceee);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script><ul>



<li class="radio">
<input class="tmcp-field nav nav-pills fabric-layer-pattern test  tm-product-image tm-epo-field tmcp-radio use_images" data-image="http://localhost/mbox_server/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/pattern.png" data-imagep="" data-imagel="" tabindex="37" type="radio">
<label for="tmcp_choice_14_0_37"><img class="tmlazy  radio_image" alt="Elegant" src="http://localhost/mbox_server/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/pattern.png">
  <span class="tc-label radio_image_label">Elegant</span></label>   

    <span class="price tc-price  hidden"><span class="amount">500</span>      </span>       
   </li>



  <li class="radio">
        <input class="tmcp-field nav nav-pills fabric-layer-pattern test  tm-product-image tm-epo-field tmcp-radio use_images"  type="radio">
  <label for="tmcp_choice_14_1_38"><img class="tmlazy  radio_image" alt="Elegant" src="http://localhost/mbox_server/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/pattern.png">
   <span class="tc-label radio_image_label">Elegant</span></label>  
      <span class="price tc-price  hidden"><span class="amount">600</span>   </span>        

 </li>

 <li class="radio">
  <input class="tmcp-field nav nav-pills fabric-layer-pattern test  tm-product-image tm-epo-field tmcp-radio use_images" type="radio">
  <label for="tmcp_choice_14_2_39"><img class="tmlazy  radio_image" alt="Elegant" src="http://localhost/mbox_server/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/pattern.png">
  <span class="tc-label radio_image_label">Elegant</span></label>   
 <span class="price tc-price  hidden"><span class="amount">700</span>     </span>       

</li>

</ul>
```

Comment: I have used your script first two time it is returning empty alert after that returning price & again two more empty alerts are coming why this is happening..

Comment: I didn't use any alert in my code, please show my your full code to check what's the exact problem.
I've used `parent` to specifically find `span` from that li only. See my working example

Comment: See I've updated my HTML in my example, it's working fine. Show me your script that show multiple alerts.

Comment: Is everything ok ?

Comment: I have updated my JS , my alert is excuting 5 times third time i am getting price rest of the alerts is coming empty..i d'nt know why..

Comment: See the updated example, it's calling once only when you click on radio.

Comment: hello i have tried simple alert it's returning five alerts with hello message like this i have tried     $('.fabric-layer-patternss').click(function() {
   alert('hello');

    });

Comment: How many class with fabric-layer-patternss available in your page ?

Comment: As you seen in my code, it's working fine. And why you worried about alert, can you see the console ?

Comment: Try $('li > .fabric-layer-patternss').click(function(){ });

Comment: hey man this is working ....thanx man I appreciate your help...thank you very much..

Comment: Glad to see that finally it helped you :) Happy Coding.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [`siblings()`](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/):

```
$('.fabric-layer-pattern').click(function() {
     var spanEl = $(this).siblings().filter("span.amount");
     var price = spanEl.text(); //Get text
});
```

`$(this)` inside the event scope is the radio input itself and `span.amount` is not inside it.

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ofpum3o8/)

Comment: This will fail assuming there's more than one

Comment: @j08691 don't seems to be the op case, but ok, I have updated.

Answer (score 1):

***UPDATE***

> I have tried but in third alert i am getting price before that empty alert is coming

This can have different meanings. With only this comment I may figure out the price value is changed outside and you are interested in that event.
If it is so, you may refer to [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver). Moreover, instead  of click event you may consider to use the change event.
According to this considerations I updated the snippet.

You may use [closest](https://api.jquery.com/closest/):

> For each element in the set, get the first element that matches the selector by testing the element itself and traversing up through its ancestors in the DOM tree

The snippet:

```js
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
    if (mutation.addedNodes.length > 0) {
      $('.fabric-layer-pattern').trigger('click');
    }
  });
});
observer.observe($('li.radio span.amount').get(0), { attributes: true, childList: true });

// later, you can stop observing
// observer.disconnect();


$('#myBtn').on('click', function(e) {
  $('li.radio span.amount').text(Date.now());
});



$('.fabric-layer-pattern').on('click', function() {
  var spanEl = $(this).closest('li.radio').find('span.amount');
  var price = spanEl.text(); //Get text
  console.log('span.amount is: ' + price);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<button type="button" id="myBtn">Change price</button>
<ul>



    <li class="radio">
        <input class="tmcp-field nav nav-pills fabric-layer-pattern test  tm-product-image tm-epo-field tmcp-radio use_images" data-image="http://localhost/mbox_server/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/pattern.png" data-imagep="" data-imagel="" tabindex="37" type="radio">
        <label for="tmcp_choice_14_0_37"><img class="tmlazy  radio_image" alt="Elegant" src="http://localhost/mbox_server/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/pattern.png">
            <span class="tc-label radio_image_label">Elegant</span></label>

        <span class="price tc-price  hidden"><span class="amount">500</span>      </span>
    </li>



    <li class="radio">
        <input class="tmcp-field nav nav-pills fabric-layer-pattern test  tm-product-image tm-epo-field tmcp-radio use_images"  type="radio">
        <label for="tmcp_choice_14_1_38"><img class="tmlazy  radio_image" alt="Elegant" src="http://localhost/mbox_server/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/pattern.png">
            <span class="tc-label radio_image_label">Elegant</span></label>
        <span class="price tc-price  hidden"><span class="amount">500</span>   </span>

    </li>

    <li class="radio">
        <input class="tmcp-field nav nav-pills fabric-layer-pattern test  tm-product-image tm-epo-field tmcp-radio use_images" type="radio">
        <label for="tmcp_choice_14_2_39"><img class="tmlazy  radio_image" alt="Elegant" src="http://localhost/mbox_server/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/pattern.png">
            <span class="tc-label radio_image_label">Elegant</span></label>
        <span class="price tc-price  hidden"><span class="amount">500</span>     </span>

    </li>

</ul>
```

Comment: I have tried but in third alert i am getting price before that empty alert is coming

Answer (score 0):

I guess this will do:

```
// Just to be specific
$(".fabric-layer-pattern + span.price > span.amount").text();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
$('.fabric-layer-pattern').click(function() {
     var price = $('span.amount').text();         
});
```